# Checkboxes with array model in angularjs using asp.mvc

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am using Asp.MVC 5 for an application and I want to generate many checkboxes with different angularjs models, and I thought the best option is by using array model in angularjs. I tried the code below inside a `foreach`:

```
   @{
        int i = 0;
        foreach (var selectedVesselViewModel in Model.SelectedVesselViewModels)
        {
            using (Html.BeginForm("SelectNotificaiton", "Admin", new { area = "DashBoard" }, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "filterVesselsForm_" + i}))
            {
                @Html.HiddenFor(item => selectedVesselViewModel.VesselId, new {ng_model= "SelectedVessels[" + i + "].VesselId" })
                <li class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <a href="#" class="text-admin-area">
                            @selectedVesselViewModel.VesselName
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">        
                        <div class="pull-right">
                            <div class="checkbox checkbox-inline">
                                @Html.CheckBoxFor(item => selectedVesselViewModel.Selected,
                               new {id = "SelectedVesselViewModels_"+i+"__Selected",
                                   onchange ="document.getElementById('filterVesselsForm_"+i+"').submit()",
                                   ng_model = "SelectedVessels[" + i + "].Selected"
                               })
                                <label for="SelectedVesselViewModels_@(i++)__Selected"></label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            }
        }
    }
```

`i` variable is an incrementing variable:

in the angularjs controller I have something like this:

```
(function (app) {
"use strict";
app.controller("DashboardCtrl", ['$scope',
    function ($scope) {
        function init() {
          // $scope.SelectedVessels = [];
        }

        $scope.SelectedVessels = [];
        init();
        $scope.RefreshSideBarVessels = function() {
            angular.forEach($scope.SelectedVessels, function (value, key) {
                alert($scope.SelectedVessels[key].VesselId);
            });
        }
    }]);
 })(adminModule);
```

When I use angularjs foreach loop the `$scope.SelectedVessels` seems to be empty but I dont know why!

```
 angular.forEach($scope.SelectedVessels, function (value, key) {
         alert($scope.SelectedVessels[key].Selected);
 });
```

Does anybody know where is the problem, why I cant access the inner properties of the `$scope.SelectedVessels` array and why it is empty ?

Comment: where in the code that $scope.SelectedVessels  is populated ?

Comment: in the controller. I tried in ng-init but did not work

Comment: you question is not clear to me yet. Can you share your code , if possible via plunker or jsfiddle ?

Comment: Oki I will prepare a asp.mvc fiddle for you shortly

Comment: @yesIcan you can see my edit now. I was hoping that the $scope.SelectedVessels will be populated in the foeach loop in c# code

Comment: so you are saying ' @Html.CheckBoxFor(item => selectedVesselViewModel.Selected,
                               new {id = "SelectedVesselViewModels_"+i+"__Selected",
                                   onchange ="document.getElementById('filterVesselsForm_"+i+"').submit()",
                                   ng_model = "SelectedVessels[" + i + "].Selected"
                               })' is the code where $scope.SelectedVessels is populated ?       specifically ng_model = "SelectedVessels[" + i + "].Selected" this code?

Comment: @yesIcan yes thats correct

Comment: posted a code, I did not try it (that is why I asked if you could share ur code via plunker or jsfiddle so that anyone who wants to help can test their code with urs)  but I think it could work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution to this problem:
I had to use `ng-init` to each checkbox to instantiate the ng-model.

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(item => selectedVesselViewModel.Selected,
   new {id = "SelectedVesselViewModels_"+i+"__Selected",
       onchange ="document.getElementById('filterVesselsForm_"+i+"').submit()",
       ng_model = "SelectedVessels[" + i + "].Selected",
       ng_init = "SelectedVessels[" + i + "].Selected="+ selectedVesselViewModel.Selected.ToString().ToLower()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

How you are adding values to your array ie. $scope.SelectedVessels is  important
Please have a look at below example.

```
var values = {name: 'Raja', gender: 'male'};
var log = [];
angular.forEach(values, function(value, key) {
this.push(key + ': ' + value);
}, log);
expect(log).toEqual(['name: Raja', 'gender: male']);
```

Comment: The values are being added inside the view in c# code because the model of the view has a list `selectedVesselViewModel`, so they come from backend. At the end I have a list of checkboxes some checked and some not checked. But I need to access those values in angularjs as well

Comment: From where you are calling this method _RefreshSideBarVessels _

Comment: it is another button above the foreach loop, so when i click it I suspect to see all the values of the array model one by one inside the alert message

Comment: Sorry for Another stupid question, your html/MVC has allocated/Bind to correct controller ie. DashboardCtrl

Comment: Instead of calling 
`RefreshSideBarVessels ()`
 method ,try to pass 
`RefreshSideBarVessels (SelectedVessels)` from button onclick put debugger in  RefreshSideBarVessels  and check that you are getting values in passes parameter or not.

 `$scope.RefreshSideBarVessels = function(SelectedVessels,) {
            angular.forEach(SelectedVessels, function (value, key) {
                alert(SelectedVessels[key].VesselId);
            });
        }`

this might solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

First off , its ng-model not ng_model  (- vs _)  but that could be typo.
Second, try this code

```
$scope.onChange = function (index, value) {
      $scope.SelectedVessels[index] = value;
}
@Html.CheckBoxFor(item => selectedVesselViewModel.Selected,
SelectedVessels[i] = selectedVesselViewModel.Selected
       new {id = "SelectedVesselViewModels_"+i+"__Selected",
           onchange ="document.getElementById('filterVesselsForm_"+i+"').submit()",
           ng-model = "SelectedVessels[" + i + "].Selected", 
           on-change="onChange(i,selectedVesselViewModel.Selected)
       })
```

Comment: It does not work this way either, for the ng_model it is correct since asp.mvc will translate it to ng-model when the page is rendered. Anyway thanks for your help :)